# Given "www.mydomain.com" - how to determine if site supports https

Tags: c#, .net, http, https

Given a partial URL such as "www.mydomain.com", how can one determine if the corresponding website supports https connections using .Net/C#?

Comment: call it with https://... and check for any exceptions

Comment: If you intercept an https call, then you would find the data encrypted, which is not the case with http. Generally https supported sites do not support http or redirect the call to the https, signing certificate details can be seen in the browser itself

Comment: @SirRufo, can you be more specific about what you mean by "call it" and what type of exception I would anticipate?

Comment: Read about HttpClient https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples - in GetAsync change http to https

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look at `System.Web` namespace:

```
HttpRequest.IsSecureConnection
```

property.

Url here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.issecureconnection?view=netframework-4.7.2

This property checks if the http connection supports https.

In Asp.net webapi, one can check if `Request.RequestUri.Scheme` is `Uri.UriSchemeHttps.`